# I have the cups app installed but unable to active the app how do I fix it?

Tags: printing, 20.04

I have confirmed cups is on my guest machine(virtual box 6.1)but the app will not respond. There is no icon for the app.

Comment: Have you tried the web interface?

Comment: Or the "Printing" control panel?